# Почему не работает LayoutParams для SubTitlePanel?

Tags: java, android

`private LinearLayout subtitlePanel;`

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) subtitlePanel.getLayoutParams();
    float dp=Utils.convertPixelsToDp(30f,context);
    if (bMargin) layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    else layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0, (int) dp);
    subtitlePanel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="@color/transparent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/subtitlePanel"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleLeftButton"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_prev_white"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:text="textsd"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleRightButton"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_next_white"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
 public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
```

Я хочу программно изменить margin в subtitlePanel. Но в место того чтобы изменилось marginBottom на 30 dp. Он изменяется на 5 dp.

Тоесть наглядно видно чтобы на пару пиксель панель поднимается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Секрет кроется в этих строчках:

```
float dp=Utils.convertPixelsToDp(30f,context);
...
layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0, (int) dp);
```

Вы 30 пикселей конвертировали в dp, после чего передали dp в метод, принимающий пиксели.

Передавайте значения в пикселях напрямую без конвертации.